# A Query inside a Query.. Long loading time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Heyy i think i need to do a query inside a query.
Here is what i tried to do(it seems to work but it takes forever to load) :

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM Table1"; 
$results=mysql_query($query); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)){
$bnr=$row['COL 1'];
$usg=$row['COL 19'];
echo"$bnr hat $usg <br /> "; 
$sqlupdate="UPDATE TABLE_1 
        SET
        Usg='$usg'
        WHERE 
            bnr = '$bnr'"; 
mysql_query($sqlupdate); 
}
```

Comment: Having an UPDATE or any type of query inside a loop could cause it to slow down.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Unless, maybe, you used a transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, updating many rows individually will take a long time regardless of whether you're doing it inside another query.

But certainly running two queries on the same database, at the same time will not help the situation at all!

That said, the good news is that in your example you're able to perform the update entirely on the server using an update with a join.

```
  UPDATE TABLE_1 as TDest 
         INNER JOIN TABLE1 as TSrc
                 ON TDest.bnr = TSrc.`COL 1`
     SET TDest.Usg = TSrc.`COL 19`
```

Comment: Even shorter: `UPDATE Table1,TABLE_1 SET TABLE_1.Usg = Table1.usg WHERE Table1.bnr = TABLE_1.bnr` ;-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat good point! :) But I wasn't trying to make it short.. just trying to make it easy to follow..

Comment: I think that's Microsoft SQL Server syntax for multi-table UPDATE. MySQL implements the syntax a bit differently (both are extensions to standard SQL).

Answer (score 2):

I think the MySQL query that you want is:

```
update tdest t1 join
       tdest t2
       on t1.bnr = t2.`Col 1`
    set t1.usg = t2.`Col 19`;
```